# Counting items on tables

Tags: sql

I need your help. I have this code to query my machines which are on rental, on stock, and on my outlets, but this only works if I input an itemID, which means it will only query one item at a time. I need to query the number of machines on rental and on outlets, parallel to the number of stock on hand.

```
alter procedure GetItemsForQueries
@itemID varchar(15)
as begin 
select i.ItemName, m.MachineModel, i.SellingPrice, i.QuantityOnHand, 
(select COUNT(*) from ClientMachine where AcquisitionType = 'Rental' and ItemID = @itemID) as 'Quantity on Rentals',
(select COUNT(*) from OutletMachine where ItemID = @itemID) as 'Quantity on Outlets'
from Item i inner join Machine m on (m.ItemID = i.ItemID)
where i.ItemID = @itemID
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two subqueries should do it - something like this...

In a nutshell, find all the machines, join against a subquery which finds the count id thats rental and join again against another subquery that finds the count per outlet machine...

```
select m.itemid, 
       ifnull(ccount,0) as rental_count,
       ifnull(ocount,0) as outlet_count
from Machine m
left join (select itemid,
             count(*) as ccount
             from ClientMachine 
             where AcquisitionType = 'Rental' group by ItemID) a1 on (a1.itemid=m.itemid)
left join (select itemid,
             count(*) as ocount
             from OutletMachine group by ItemID) a2 on (a2.itemid=m.itemid)
```

Comment: just added some codes to your answer, and this one seems to be the nearest of what i need . thank you !

Comment: thanks!  pretty much everyone did the same thing, its a really common pattern you'll use over and over when writing queries.

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head (could have some syntax errors but the logic is there)

```
select i.ItemId, i.ItemName, m.MachineModel, i.SellingPrice, i.QuantityOnHand, rental.rentalCount, outlet.outletCount
from Item i
left join (select ItemId, count(*) as 'rentalCount' from ClientMachine Where AcquisitionType = 'Rental' group by ItemId) rental on rental.ItemId = i.ItemId
left join (select ItemId, count(*) as 'outletCount' from OutletMachine group by ItemId) outlet on outlet.ItemId = i.ItemId
inner join Machine m on (m.ItemID = i.ItemID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code :

```
select i.ItemName, 
       m.MachineModel, 
       i.SellingPrice, 
       i.QuantityOnHand, 
       (select COUNT(*) from ClientMachine where AcquisitionType = 'Rental' and ItemID =            i.ItemID) as 'Quantity on Rentals',
       (select COUNT(*) from OutletMachine where ItemID = i.ItemID) as 'Quantity on Outlets'
from Item i inner join Machine m on (m.ItemID = i.ItemID)
```